# Remove duplicate documents from base set of documents for aggregation

Tags: mongodb

The script below results in a single record which is due to a problem I have with the FIRST $group I have setup which is designed to select the $first version of a document (by the criteria set out in the group).

What I think it's doing is selecting the $first company and connection along with the first transaction_date which results in 6 documents that match for that criteria before it then does an $unwind, $match and $group to $sum values by month.

If I try removing some $first on any of the fields, it complains about that value not being an accumulative.

**How do I make that first group simply look at the documents processed by the sort and exclude older duplicate versions of a document where the _id.company, _id.connection and _id.transaction_date are the same?**

I believe my method is right but I've made a schoolboy error.

```
db.getCollection("9SP_Data").aggregate([

// find documents of a type and within a number range
{"$match" : {"_id.object_category" : "revenue-transaction"
        ,"_id.transaction_date": {
            $gte: 20160101000000,
            $lt: 20170101000000
            },
}},


// sort into order so that if duplicates, the new document listed at top
{$sort : { "_id.connection":1,
       "_id.company":1,
       "_id.transaction_reference":1,
       "_id.transaction_date":-1,
       "object_creation_date": -1 }},

{$group : { _id: "$_id.transaction_reference",  
            "company" : {$first : "$_id.company"},
            "connection" : {$first : "$_id.connection"}, 
            "transaction_date" : {$first : "$_id.transaction_date"}, 
            "object_category" : {$first : "$_id.object_category"}, 
            "object_origin_category" : {$first : "$_id.object_origin_category"}, 
            "object_origin_type" : {$first : "$_id.object_origin_type"}, 
            "object_origin" : {$first : "_id.$object_origin"}, 
            "transaction_status" : {$first: "$_id.transaction_status"}, 
            "line_items" : {$first: "$line_items"}}},

    {"$unwind" :  "$line_items"},
    {"$match"  :  {"line_items.item_category":"sales-revenue"}},
    {"$group" : {
       "_id":
           {
            "company" : "$connection",
            "sum_by_date":  {$trunc:{ $divide: ["$transaction_date", 100000000 ]}},
            //  10000000000 - by year
            //  100000000 - by month 
            //  1000000 - by date 
            //  10000 - by hour 
            //  100 - by minute 
            "category" : "$line_items.item_category",
            "origin_category" : "$object_origin_category",
            "object_origin_type" : "$object_origin_type",
            "object_origin" : "$object_origin"
           },
        "metric_value"  : { $sum: "$line_items.item_net_total_value" },

        // count number of documents (I think this is counting line_items but I need number of distinct documents by _id.transaction_reference)
        "metric_volume":{$sum:1}}
},

// format the output to include the following values
{$project : {
    "_id.company"               : "$_id.company",
    "_id.metric_name"           : {$literal : "revenue"},
    "_id.metric_category"       : {$literal : "sales"},
    "_id.metric_type"           : {$literal : "month"},
    "_id.metric_lookup"         : "$_id.sum_by_date",
    "_id.object_origin_category": "$origin_category",
    "_id.object_origin_type"    : "$object_origin_type",
    "_id.object_origin"         : "$object_origin",
    "metric_value"              : "$metric_value",
    "metric_volume"             : "$metric_volume"
    }}
])
```

Comment: Hi guys, I'm still stuck on the removing duplicates from data set before processing. Thanks, Matt

Comment: Happy New Year people of Stack Overflow, I'm still stuck on this problem, please help, thanks